# Solving synchronization problems in asynchronous programs

Tags: java, node.js, asynchronous, synchronization, vert.x

I am developing 2 projects using asynchronous technology Vert.x and Node.js and MongoDB. Both projects have the feature of booking airline tickets, there will certainly be cases where many people book the same ticket at the same time. sometimes, there will be data inconsistency problem. So I think the solution is to use synchronisation, but what I'm worried about is that using sync in an async application will cause
performance issue where threads are blocked until processed, affecting user experience.
So is there any way to achieve this? Is it good to use synchronization in this case? I would be very grateful and appreciated if someone share me a solution to this problem. Forgive me as this is my first time working with asynchronous applications. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

With Vert.x you could make use of the event bus. The [`send` method](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/eventbus/EventBus.html#send-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) will deliver a message to **at most one handler** registered on an address. That way you shouldn't need synchronization. When you mix in a node app, then you could make use of a similar system using a [message queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) where only one consumer would work on a booking.

There's also a vert.x event bus bridge for node that you could take a look at [here](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-eventbus-bridge-clients).

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. However the 2 apps I talked about are independent of each other, we write both apps to see which works better. Vertx - mongoDB and Node.Js with MongoDB. They are independent and do not communicate with each other. Our focus of development is Vert.x. So your solution is to use "send" method of "eventBus" it still work without synchronization when working with database right?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use optimistic locking on Mongo side. More details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control